# spring boot multiple modules multiple property files @Propertysource not working

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have 1 main project and 1 dependent project auditmodule. Auditmodule has its own datasource , and database properties are in auditapplication.properties. Main application has its own application.properties.Main project depends on audit project for auditing stuff. When I run my main application , it's not detecting auditapplication.properties in audit module.

Below are the databaseconfiguration classes in main project and in audit project:

Main project:

```
@Configuration            
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "com.staples.mpe.repository", entityManagerFactoryRef = "mpeEntityManager", transactionManagerRef = "mpeTransactionManager")            
@EnableTransactionManagement            
public class DatabaseConfiguration implements EnvironmentAware {}
```

Audit project:

```
@Configuration    
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "com.staples.em.magnus.audit.repository", entityManagerFactoryRef = "auditEntityManager")    
@EnableTransactionManagement    
@PropertySource("classpath:auditapplication.properties")    
public class AuditDatabaseConfiguration implements EnvironmentAware {
}
```

I have mentioned @propertysource annotation on auditdatabaseconfiguration class, so when i run main project , it should not only detect application.properties in main project but should also detect auditapplication.properties in audit project.

But its throwing error that it can't configure auditdatasource bean which is pulling the properties from auditapplication.properties.

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: A stack trace would help?

Comment: Thanks you so much for replying. I am able to solve the issue, i used @PropertySource("classpath:auditapplication.properties") , but in auditapplication.properties, i had yml format so thats why it was not recognizing the properties. I changed from yml format to key=value format in the property file.